# Get Corner Coordinates TIFF file

Tags: javascript, gdal, geotiff

I'm using a javascript app to get the borders coordinates of a [TIFF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OW8l5Xe0dV1KM9h1hvudEXM5_L7uzsPM/view?usp=sharing) file. I'm having trouble getting these coordinates. I'm using this [example](https://github.com/naturalatlas/node-gdal/blob/a869bf74999b0004a8dac9193bb04a669f422dec/examples/gdalinfo.js), but the corner coordinates are returning incorrectly.

The correct thing would be to return coordinates lng -51... and lat -25...

Answer (score 0):

This is the output I get with `node examples/gdalinfo.js`:

```
Upper Left   (-5721999.51, -2925751.47) ( 25d24'23.23"W,  51d24' 5.75"S)
Upper Right  (-5721770.19, -2925751.47) ( 25d24'23.23"W,  51d23'58.33"S)
Bottom Right (-5721770.19, -2926104.99) ( 25d24'33.56"W,  51d23'58.33"S)
Bottom Left  (-5721999.51, -2926104.99) ( 25d24'33.56"W,  51d24' 5.75"S)
Center       (-5721884.85, -2925928.23) ( 25d24'28.40"W,  51d24' 2.04"S)
```

The first numbers par is in the projected coordinates system, the second pair is in WGS84.

The example uses `gdal.CoordinateTransformation` and `gdal.decToDMS` to obtain this result.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation and I understand perfectly. However, this return gdal.decToDMS is not in lng, lat decimal format. How do I convert this to decimal.

Comment: Then you don't need `gdal.decToDMS`, the return value of `gdal.CoordinateTransformation` is the result you need